# Dynamically add html to page

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

At the moment I'm developing a javascript based page, which has an initial form for login and then a list of information is presented based on the logged user.

The problem I'm facing at the moment is that the div that contains the list can only be loaded after the login, so I can't use PHP variables (can't change value after page loaded).

I was trying to only insert the content (list) after the login was successful (done with Ajax), so I tried to change the HTML of the div, but since I have to use a @foreach on a php variable and then @include a page for each element, I can't seem to be able to do it.

```
$("#topics-list").html(function() {
       var html = [];

       @foreach($topics as $topic)
           @php
               $topic = (object)$topic;
           @endphp

           @include('frontend::cbs.topic', [ 'topic' => $topic, 'toSubmit' => !$allSubmitted ])
       @endforeach

       return html;
});
```

Comment: make an ajax call to get the topics from server and then  loop the result with JS. You can even call for the whole HTML from server and just append it in your page, but it would be better/easier to just redirect to a new page.

Comment: don't know if you would like this, but https://laravel-livewire.com/ is just the right thing for such use cases. You get complete ajax calls to the server in the frontend and pure PHP and laravel utilities in the backend component code.